# Rails 3 Authentication solution update?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, authorization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I poked around StackOverflow and Google, but I found articles little too older that has put together a comparison of authentication gems or plugins for Rails (and there is surely an update needed on latest research, reviews and comments). What authentication solutions are available for Rails 3, which are most popular, and what are the differences between them?

Comment: devise still rules the world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the ruby toolbox here

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication

I recommend using devise because it pretty much offers anything you could want from an authentication system

You'll also find lots of tutorials and support for it all over the internet

If you're looking for something simpler you could try sorcery, which offers pretty basic stuff and it's very customizable

Both of these are also covered in Ryan Bates' railscasts

Comment: devise still rules the world?

Comment: I think devise is still pretty relevant. Version 2.0 was just released a couple months ago.